# How to instantiate an NSObject in the Interface builder .xib file

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder, nsobject

Greetings,

I have a view based application project where I have created an NSObject class called "SquareClass".
Now, from the Xcode's interface builder, I want to be able to instantiate that "SquareClass" into a square object with global scope, in such a way that, when I create actions from any UI controls(i.e textboxes, buttons etc...), I want to be able to call methods of that object within those actions.

**example:**

```
(void)MyAction1:(id)color
{
   [square setColor:color];
}

(void)MyAction2:(id)width
{
   [square setWidth:width];
}
```

As you can see, the square object needs to have a global scope.
This might seems easy or maybe the wrong way of doing it for some of us.
I've look through the web, and kinda found a way for a .nib file, not for a .xib file.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Yohann.

*ps: This is my first post EVER, be indulgent.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, a NIB file is, for all intents and purposes, the same as an XIB file; it’s just a compiled version of a XIB file.

Now, to create an object derived from NSObject in your NIB/XIB, simply drag an NSObject from the library window into your file. Then on the Identity Inspector change the class to your custom class.

If you define methods like this:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
```

you’ll be able to hook them up in Interface Builder.

Having said all that, it’s difficult to tell whether what you’re doing is the right thing to do at all. It sounds to me like you should be using an NSViewController subclass so have a look at the documentation for that.

You should also make sure you understand what view, controller and model objects are. There’s plenty of literature on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class extending UIView, then you can make the File's Owner for your xib implement the extended class.  From that point simply add an instance variable to your extended class for the square.  The last step in the process is to add methods to your class to bind to each of the controls to actions.

```
- (IBAction) pinSelected: (id)sender;
```

Once you create these methods (be sure to make them return IBAction, it is actually an alias for void but acts as a hint to INterface Builder) then you can bind your controls to the method through File's Owner (using control + drag to establish the link).

Good Luck!

Comment: By default, the project gets a SquareController and SquareDelegate classes. I believe one of those can extend UIView, right? Should that class instantiate the square? If so, should the instantiation code be right after the @implementation declaration?

Comment: I would add an separate class for your custom view.  He App Delegate should really only handle application-scope things as the app is built up and torn down.  The controller is likely a UIViewController whose main purpose is to manage instances of UIViews.

Comment: I'm having trouble doing what you're suggesting. Do you mind using baby steps?
 When You say: "If you create a class extending UIView, then you can make the File's Owner for your xib implement the extended class."
I now have a class extending UIView, how do I extend the file's Owner? I can't seem to be able to edit it. What I could do was to change the Class Identity of the File's Owner to "SquareClass". Is this what you meant? Then once I add actions, how do I implement them please?

Comment: Sure.  I would do things like this:
1)  Create your "square" class based on NSObject. (Done)
2)  Create a "squareView" class extending UIView.
3)  Add action methods to your squareView class for each thing you want to do (like changeWidth:)
4)  Open your xib in Interface Builder.  Click on File's Owner and set the Class Identity to "squareView".
5)  Now add the different controls you may need to you View (like buttons, etc)
6)  Hold control and click/drag from the control onto File's Owner.  It will drag a blue arrow until you release the mouse button.  Pick the event to bind the control to.

Comment: Thanx a Lot MystikSpiral, I'll try this as soon as I get out of work, and let you know.

Comment: I don't see at what step the relation between square and squareView is created (instantiation? inheritance? drag-click? osmosis?)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do what I needed which is NOT done within the XIB file. It is way simpler than what i thought, eventhough the above suggestions are VALID.

In order to use the square object, I just had to reference the header file:

```
 #import "square.h"
```

in the SquareUIViewController.h and add a reference to a square object:

```
Square *square;
```

Then in the SquareUIController.m, I just have to allocate/initialize the square object prior doing anything else:

```
(IBAction)myInit
{
square = [[Square alloc] init];
}
```

Now I can use the methods of the first post
And Voila !

ps: critics, fire up!