# how to I introduce use of a NIB file to my existing custom UIView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

how to I introduce use of a NIB file to my existing custom UIView?  For example:

a) should the NIB load automatically somehow if named the name as the *.h & *.m file?  (i.e. I'm talking about a custom UIView here, not a UIControllerView)

b) if you have to do it manually do you need to use "[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIBfilename" owner:self options:nil];" perhaps?

c) if yes (to b above), then in whether method do you do this, in the custom view's "- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder" method?

PS. For use in discussion with @Katfish's answer.  Katfish, when I put the "NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]..." line in I get a recursive loop of hits to "initWithCoder"?   [PS see comment I just made to @sergio's answer, which might explain this?]

```
// Code within my custom UIView
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClockView" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
        .
        .
        .
    }
    return self;
}
```

PSS. Noting that status of where I'm up to here (see comments in Sergio's answer) I am now wondering whether what I'm doing is possible at all?  Based on seeing [Custom UIView from Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869424/custom-uiview-from-interface-builder) .  Perhaps I could create a custom UIView but only ever use via creating/instantiating it programmatically from the UIControllerView I'm calling it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) should the NIB load automatically somehow if named the name as the *.h & *.m file? (i.e. I'm talking about a custom UIView here, not a UIControllerView)

As far as I know, nibs are not loaded automatically, except for MainWindow, which is loaded by UIKit according to what it specified in info.plist;

> b) if you have to do it manually do you need to use "[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIBfilename" owner:self options:nil];" perhaps?

`loadNibNamed` is a good option if you do not want to instantiate a view controller and need just an array of the top object you defined in your nib;

> c) if yes (to b above), then in whether method do you do this, in the custom view's "- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder" method?

I would use `initWithCoder` if you are loading the base view from a nib, `initWithFrame` if you create it programmatically.

EDIT:

As to your PS, I guess that you set one of the object in your xib file to be an instance of the `UIView` subclass where you define `initWithCoder`. (e.g., if your `UIView` subclass is `MyView`, then you also instantiated a view object in the xib and set its class to `MyView`).

If this is the case, what you need to do is define the File's Owner to the concrete derived `UIView` class (e.g., `MyView`); indeed you are already instantiating the `UIView` derived class and when loading the nib you only need specifying the file's owner (through the `owner` argument).

EDIT 2:

oh actually I see that in fact I have (a) in the parent UIControllerView which uses my custom view, in IB for it's XIB I use a UIView which I've set the classname to "clockview", but then (b) in my actual clockview custom UIView (not UIControllerView) XIB file I've done the same thing and set the class name to be "clockview". Do you know what classname I should be using for (a) parent UIControllerView and (b) the custom UIView itself here? (getting a bit confused) – Greg 1 hour ago

After reading your comment, you have two ways of doing it.:

First Option

1. in your `UIViewController` related xib, you are doing right;
2. in your other xib file, remove the custom `UIView` (the one you assigned the class name `clockview`; this object will be already created by the xib of point 1, so you don't need to instantiate it again); select the File's Owner of this "other xib" and set its class name to `clockwork`.

In this case, you would define `initWithCoder` as you did previously. Drawback of this is that you instantiate objects in one nib and the view in the other; you won't be able to define the clockview view in the second nib. So,...

Second Option

1. in your `UIViewController` related xib, change the `UIView` class name and set it to `UIView`; this view will be thus a "normal" view that you will use as an empty view to host the other view from the second xib file;
2. in your other xib file, leave things as they are; possibly you could set the File's Owner in this case to the `UIViewController` of point 1.

I think that this second case is the one that you are aiming at. In this case, you don't need to do anything specific in your clockview's `initWithCoder`; what you need is, in your *`UIViewController`*, load the xib view when appropriate; typically this could be in `viewDidLoad` (or elsewhere, possibly after you click on a button, it depends on your app):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClockView" owner:self options:nil];
     for (NSObject *obj in nibs) {
        if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[clockview class]]) {
            [self addSubview:(clockview*)obj];
            break;
        }
     }
  }
```

What I am doing in this `viewDidLoad` is identifying the clockwork view that is instantiated by loading the second xib file; and adding it to the controller's view as a subview.

Again, observe the `controller` argument that I passed to `loadNibNamed`; this must correspond to the object you specified as file's owner of the second xib.

I think that it should work in this way.

Comment: thanks Sergio - I posted a PS to my question as when I try this I'm getting a recursive loop of hits to "initWithCoder"?

Comment: oh actually I see that in fact I have (a) in the parent UIControllerView which uses my custom view, in IB for it's XIB I use a UIView which I've set the classname to "clockview", but then (b) in my actual clockview custom UIView (not UIControllerView) XIB file I've done the same thing and set the class name to be "clockview".  Do you know what classname I should be using for (a) parent UIControllerView and (b) the custom UIView itself here?  (getting a bit confused)

Comment: Based on seeing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869424/custom-uiview-from-interface-builder .  Perhaps I could create a custom UIView but only ever use via creating/instantiating it programmatically from the UIControllerView I'm calling it from?

Comment: thanks sergio - just digesting this at the moment :) - will let you know how I go

Answer (score 0):

In general, Write a class yourController which is inherited from NSObject and set the file owner of the nib to yourController class. And in yourController class handle nib loading([[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIBfilename" owner:self options:nil]).
And if you want to initialize some data to the view which is loaded from the nib use initWithCoder method.

Comment: did you understand that I'm creating an XIB file for a UIView (not a UIControllerView)?  So currently I have a (a) mainViewController within which one of the views in it's XIB file is a UIView for which the class name I've allocated in IB is "ClockView", then separately to this I have (b) my custom UIView for which I'm trying to add a XIB to the existing *.h and *.m.  Just trying to understanding your suggestion in light of this, and what you're suggesting to go in the parent view controller versus the custom clock UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a nib to a UIView in `- (id)init`.

```
- (id)init {

    NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NIBfilename" owner:self options:nil];
    self = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    [self retain];

    return self;

}
```

Comment: thanks, perhaps the 2nd line is what's missing for me - can you give a quick overview of what "self = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];" does?  Would I need to make this call first off in the init method then I suppose else it would override any settings I'd already made for the view in the init?

Comment: tried this, when I put the "NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle]..." line in I get a recursive loop of hits to "initWithCoder"?  I posted the code as a PS in my question.

Comment: is that allowed? No memory leaks?

Comment: @xpepermint It is allowed. Since there is no call to `[super init]`, the only thing increasing the ref count here is that retain call, so when the view is later released by its controller, there should be no leaks.

Comment: @Katfish and you call the class like [[ThisClass alloc] init]?

Answer (score 0):

a) If you have a NIB file, and the owner is the .h file, then when the header file, a UIViewContoller subclass is loaded with the [alloc] initWithNibName, then the NIB is loaded automatically.

b) YES

c) you can use the initWithNibName method.

Do you want to add a component from a .xib file to your existing UIView which is loaded already by the view controller?

Then you can load the .xib component in this way, and then get the component from the array.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {


    // open xib and find tableView
    if ( (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) ) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibNameOrNil owner:self options:nil];

        for (NSObject *obj in nibs) {
            if ( [obj isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
                self.tableContent = (UITableView *) obj;
            }
        }
        self.view = self.tableContent;              

        [self initializeDefaultValues];     
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: note my custom UIView is not a UIControllerView - I can't see that "initWithNibName" is actually available for a UIView?